# Mysql datatype for single digit - tinyint(1) or smallint(1) or int(1)

Tags: mysql, int, tinyint

I need to add a column to mysql db table for storing single digits. The digits will be **0, 1, 2**, and **3**. What should be the datatype for the column?

`tinyint(1)` or `smallint(1)` or `int(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats simple you can simply take `tinyint` for the simple reason that it takes only 1 byte(-128 to +127 / 0 to 255 (unsigned))

**On a side note:**

The reason why you can avoid the other is that smallint takes 2 bytes and int takes 4 bytes, and since you have only 4 values which you want to store so no need to waste the memory.

Answer (score 2):

TINYINT UNSIGNED

Read about integer types
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html